# jsp is not rendering on requested uri

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I am getting "welcome" on hit of localohst: instead of my welcome.jsp

Here is my controller:

```
 @RestController
    public class WelcomeController {
    // inject via application.properties
    @Value("${welcome.message:test}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }
```

StartupApplication :

```
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: Are you using embedded tomcat or any other server?

Comment: I am using embedded tomcat

 <!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>

Answer (score 2):

Your `WelcomeController` is rest controller make it normal controller with `@Controller` annotation as shown in this example.
https://medium.com/@milansavaliyaz/spring-boot-hello-world-example-with-jsp-view-7ffed2ae931d

Comment: Thanks , but I am getting error :  
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'welcome' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

Comment: what is location of your jsp? your jsp should be in /WEB-INF/jsp/ and its name should be welcome.jsp

Comment: Yes , In the same folder.